# Android: activity will be recreated after calling finish

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to create an app which contains two activities: `MainActivity` and `SubActivity`.

`SubActivity` will be created from `MainActivity` by calling `startActivityForResult()`.

When I tap the button settled in `SubActivity`, it should finish itself and go to `MainActivity`.
But I get problem with finishing `SubActivity`.
After `SubActivity.onPause()` is called, `SubActivity.onCreate()` will be called immedietly and the SubActivity will be recreated.

I just wanna close SubActivity and display `MainActivity`, but why is this happen?

I searched for same questions and found that rotation change will make the system call onCreate().
But in my case, the screen orientation fixed to portrait.

Could someone please give me an idea to solve this problem?

EDIT:
I solved the problem.
There was a wrong logic in the `MainActivity`.

`SubActivity` will be created from `MainActivity`, when a variable holds a specific value.
The display update method which reflects the value of the variable was called twice in code.
That brought my App to recreate the `SubActvity` after `finish()`.

`MainActivity` requests to create `Subactivity` twice, but since my app is set as `android:launchMode="singleTop"`, the second `SubActivity` could be only created after the first one has been finished.
Thanks a lot to give me advice!

Comment: add code for what you are doing to finish SubActivity.

Comment: `finish()` method will end current activity and back to the last in stack.

Comment: @AmitJangid I'm gonna prepare the codes to attach here.

Comment: @grabarz121 I believed that the top of the last stack is MainActivity, but it might be not. I try to get the activity's name of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use or first check the behaviour of,

1)`finishAffinity();`

2)`finishActivityFromChild();`

May it work.

Otherwise for better communication put some line of code here so we will understand proper and give some guidance to you.

Comment: Thank you, Kunal. But both 1) and 2) went to crush. I'm gonna prepare the codes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I called below functions.

```
btn.setOnClickListener {
    setResult(result)
    finishActivity(REQUEST_CODE)
    finish()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you describe I am giving you example.
From `MainActivity` call the `SubActivity` using  startActivityForResult() method

For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Now in your `SubActivity` set the data which you want to send back to `MainActivity`. (Below is both example)

With data example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("key",result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

No data example: (If you don't have data send to `MainActivity`)

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
finish();
```

In your `MainActivity` Override `onActivityResult()` method to retrieve result.
(Only if you send data from `SubActivity`)

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String data=data.getStringExtra("key");
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}
```